What is a good translation for these verbal adjectives? (Greek)
My textbook gives the following sentence:

Πολλῶν δὴ οὖν ἕνεκα λεκτέον τι καὶ οὐ καθευδητέον ἐν τῇ μεσημβρίᾳ.

I can't find a good translation of this to english, especially regarding the modal issues implied by the two verbal adjectives.

I edited the text to reflect the actual Greek text, though it may be that your textbook introduced two typos.

Verbal adjectives in -τέος have "the general force (but not all the uses) of the Latin gerundive or participle in -ndus" (Goodell, §354)
In your example (from Plato's Phaedrus, 529d) both verbals are neuter: λεκτέον (from λέγω) goes with the indefinite pronoun τι, and καθευδητέον (from καθεύδω) is impersonal. Both verbals should be construed with an understood first-person plural pronoun: "we ought to do X" is often rendered in Greek (and in Latin) as "X ought to be done [for us]."
As a translation, breaking it up into three parts:

Πολλῶν δὴ οὖν ἕνεκα
λεκτέον τι καὶ
οὐ καθευδητέον έν τῇ μεσημβρίᾳ.


And thus for many reasons
something must be said and
we must not sleep [literally: "it must not be slept"] at noon.

